# pytest: Run test modules in a specific order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, github-actions

Let me say I'm still new to unit testing and using `pytest`.

I'm building unit tests and running them with GitHub Actions and I understand why it failed. I need to run the test modules in a specific order.

For reference, I have a following repo structure (generalized for simplicity)

```
mypackage/
├── __init__.py
├── foo.py
└── bar.py
tests/
├── __init__.py
├── test_foo.py
└── test_bar.py
```

My question (written for generalization): Is there a way to run specific test modules (not functions) in a given order with `pytest`? By default `pytest` will run in alphabetical order, i.e., `test_bar` before `test_foo`. However, in my case, `test_bar` uses data from `test_foo`, so I would like the order to be flipped. I can find other work arounds, but from my search I only found explanations of using `pytest-order` or `pytest-ordering` for specific functional orders in a *given* module. I thought this would be a good question for end-to-end testing while still ensuring 100% code coverage.

Thanks.

Comment: Pytest is a unit test framework. A unit test should be self-contained and therefore not depend on being run in a specific order.

Comment: Yes, I understand that `pytest` is for unit tests. I had built a simple unit test locally and it worked fine because the dependencies were available locally, but after my commit that's when I realized why it failed. I wanted to see if there's a way to still use my existing tests as is without refactoring it in some other way and have a separate step for additional testing.

Comment: For end-to-end, systems level testing it's best to use a completely different design.

Comment: I always name functions/files like `test_01__foo.py` and `test_02__bar.py`.

Comment: Yea I might do that but I think my CI build tests will likely need to change for other reasons.

Comment: @Keith Travis CI and other frameworks unfortunately do not execute modules self-contained; "meta" modifications (e.g. module changes) in `test_a.py` will affect `test_b.py`.

Comment: Just to let you know, I ended up adjusting my unit tests such that it is independent of order with additional tests data, etc.. For end-to-end, I ended up using executable scripts to follow the workflow for a production deployment.

Comment: @Keith Pytest is for Unit AND Integration testing.